# Null Pointer access: This variable dt_str can only be null

Tags: java

I am new to java coding getting error with my code. I was trying to get dates for the year passed to the function `ABC` by concatenating the m and d arrays with s as year. I want to use this for next part of my problem but I am stuck with

> Null Pointer access: This variable `dt_str` can only be `null`"

what am I doing wrong here?

```
public class ABC {


    public void ABC(String s)
    {
        String[] dt_str;
        String  m[] = new String[] {"01","02","03""};
        String d[]= new String[] {"01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09","10", "11","12","13","14","15"};
        for(int i=0;i<m.length;i++) {
            for (int j=0;j<d.length;j++) {
                dt_str[j]=m[i]+d[j]+s;

            }
        }
        System.out.println(dateString);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are doing exactly what the error message says, trying to use a variable that is null. Take the variable it is pointing out and give it a value before using it.

Comment: `String[] dt_str;` does not create the array, it just declares a variable (pointer) that can hold an array.

Comment: Please do not post code that does not compile.  Post the code that is actually giving you a problem.  Otherwise, we are left trying to to reproduce your problem with code that never actually generates that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually no clue what exactly you wanted to achieve with your code, since several variables are undefinied (`dateString` and `s` for example). Also is the array `m[]` definied in a wrong way (double `"` within the data part) - however, I "fixed" your code with the given information:

```
    String[] m = {"01", "02", "03"};
    String[] d = {"01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"};
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < d.length; j++) {
            sb.append(m[i] + d[j] + " ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

And this does output `0101 0102 0103 0104 0105 0106 0107 0108 0109 0110 0111 0112 0113 0114 0115 0201 0202 0203 0204 0205 0206 0207 0208 0209 0210 0211 0212 0213 0214 0215 0301 0302 0303 0304 0305 0306 0307 0308 0309 0310 0311 0312 0313 0314 0315`

Answer (score 0):

You never assign anything to `dt_str`; you try to assign to *elements* of it, but the actual array is never created.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing:

```
 String[] dt_str;
```

to

```
 String[] dt_str = new String[d.length]
```

and move it to just before the for-loop.

However, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with this method.

Comment: That would be problematic, as `d` isn't defined until later.